Using google.appengine.api.mail sends an email twice
I'm using google.appengine.api.mail to send an email.
My web-app is hosted on app-engine and starting a few months ago it suddenly sends the same email twice.
Is there any idea which GCP settings or other places to debug in order to find the reason for the double sending?


Did you make any changes - change to code, different version of the api, etc?

Not that I can think of. Nevertheless, I don't think this should happen in any API version.

Please edit the question by sharing detailed steps along with minimal code that anyone can use to replicate the behavior? Also share logs from the console by editing your question?
